# how to select values from listview column

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

how can i pick up the values from list view column, lets suppose I've following list view

```
Product Quantity                Product price           Total Price    
      2                             4                      8
      3                             4                     12
      2                             5                     10
```

now i want to pick values in `Total Price` column and add them all, means i want to add 8,12,10. how can i do it?

Comment: what you have tried ???

Comment: @Arun i've tried for loop but in different manner means i didn't take value from list view but from the variable in which the values were but it didn't work for me then i try this code :  //foreach (ListViewItem item in lvProductInfo.Items)
            {
                totalPrice = 0;

                double price = 0;
                if (double.TryParse(item.SubItems[2].Text, out price))
                    totalPrice += Convert.ToInt32(price);
            }

but still not working for me

Comment: Always it is better you add your code in question saying that this is my attempt

Comment: what error you are getting ??? Don't create XY Problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int totalPrice = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<listView1.Items.Count;i++)
        {
            totalPrice += Convert.ToInt32(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text);
        }

    }
```

Comment: @psnLoverCSharp: glad tobe help of you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a `ListViewItem` by iterating through the collection `ListView.Items`.
Each `ListViewItem` with more than one value has SubItems that are collected in the `ListViewItem.SubItem`-Collection.
            decimal sum = 0;

```
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
        {
            string _val = item.SubItems[2].Text;
            decimal totalPrice = decimal.Parse(_val);
            sum += totalPrice;
        }
```

Comment: not working for me, it just pick the last added value from the list view like from the above list view it just pick 10.

Comment: you should cast it to decimal or any other numeric datatype, 
decimal totalPrice = 0.0;
totalPrice += decimal.parse(item.SubItems[2]);

Comment: I fixxed the code and tested it, should work. I misunderstood the question.